# Unable to mount local PersistentVolume in k8s 1.13

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a stateful set with a persistent volume claim on a bare metal kubernetes cluster (v1.13) but the pod times out when trying to mount the volume.

I have a `local-storage` storage class defined:

```yaml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

I have a PV defined:

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cassandradev1
  labels:
    app: cassandra
    environment: dev
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 1Ti
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: "/data1/cassandradev1"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - my-node1
```

And I have a stateful set that issues a claim (truncated):

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cassandra-set
spec:
  ...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandra-data
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: "cassandra"
          environment: "dev"
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "local-storage"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Ti
```

When I try to apply the stateful set, the Pod gets scheduled but times out:

```bash
Normal   Scheduled    2m13s  default-scheduler            Successfully assigned default/cassandra-set-0 to my-node1
Warning  FailedMount  13s    kubelet, my-node1  Unable to mount volumes for pod "cassandra-set-0 (dd252f77-fda3-11e8-96d3-1866dab905dc)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"cassandra-set-0". list of unmounted volumes=[cassandra-data]. list of unattached volumes=[cassandra-data default-token-t2dg8]
```

If I look at the logs for the controller I see an error message for no volume plugin matched:

```bash
kubectl logs pod/kube-controller-manager -n kube-system
W1212 00:51:24.218114       1 plugins.go:845] FindExpandablePluginBySpec(cassandradev1) -> err:no volume plugin matched
```

Any ideas on where to look next?

Answer (score 0):

First of all PV definition is incorrect, there is no `hostPath` in local-storage class. This is how you should define your local storage PV:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cassandradev1
  labels:
    app: cassandra
    environment: dev
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 1Ti
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: "/data1/cassandradev1"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - my-node1
```

Also keep in mind unlike hostPath, `/data1/cassandradev1` should exist on `my-node1`, `local-storage` doesn't automatically create the path and when you deploy statefulset and path is not there, it will give error related to mounting.

This should resolve your issue. Hope this helps.

EDIT: So, I setup the cassandra statefulset with local-storage by following yaml files. I have omitted some config maps and so it will not work as it is. Could you please try to check what is different there:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  generation: 1
  labels:
    state: cassandra
  name: cassandra
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  serviceName: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        pod.alpha.kubernetes.io/initialized: "true"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - chmod -R 777 /logs/; /on_start.sh
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        image: <image>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: cassandra
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9042
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: data
        imagePullSecrets:
      - name: gcr-imagepull-json-key
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
      storageClassName: local-storage
```

PV.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  labels:
    type: local
  name: cassandra-data-vol-0
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: data-cassandra-0
    namespace: default
  local:
    path: /data/cassandra-0
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - ip-10-0-1-91.ec2.internal
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
```

Make sure `/data/cassandra-0` exists before you create PV. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Did that change in 1.13 (hostPath not being a thing)? This configuration worked for 1.12 but I can't find anything related in the release notes. I will try and see if it works.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions but it still does not work. Any other ideas of where I can look?

Comment: When I'm trying to apply the PV, I'm getting this error: "The PersistentVolume "localmount" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type" Any ideas?